# should I install RDS on an application server

Tags: rds

I recall back in the Terminal Services days that you wouldn't enable TS application mode on your business application servers just so that a team of devs/admins can RDP to the application server (i.e more than 2 RDP sessions required). Since it does things to Windows and changes the way the apps run.

Note that I'm referring to a server that hosts a business application eg JBoss application server hosting a web application. Not referring to a server for hosting remote apps (MS Office), or used as a jumpbox etc.

I'm trying to find advice on whether this is still the case with Windows 2012 R2 RDS. Searching for these terms only brings up sites for installing RDS.

The development team at my work are requesting more RDP sessions to their server environment and are asking about installing RDS on the servers. I know about the virtues of RSAT and remote deployments, but I was also curious if it will change the way the OS behaves.

Comment: No, you shouldn't install the RDS role on a server that's not strictly intended to be an RDS Session Host. Additionally, if you do install the RDS role for your stated purpose you'll also need to install the RDS License role somewhere and you'll need to purchase RDS CAL's.

Comment: I hope you don't mean that developers are playing around in production!

Comment: @Michael - no, the scenario here is really the dev team wanting more RDP sessions to their development servers.

Comment: @joeqwerty - yes, we already have a licensed RDS deployment with a gateway and session hosts for them to remote into the environment. Only now they want more sessions on the actual servers.

Comment: My first thought is that your devs don't have enough virtual machines to play with. My second thought is that your devs need to learn more PowerShell.